# creating an element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 `<section>` tags in my html file, I’ve created one more `<section>` element in js

```
const lastSection = document.createElement('section');
```

and I saved them all in a variable

```
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
```

the issue is, when I run `console.log(allSections.length);` it returns only `3`.

I want an explanation of what's going in ?

I expected it returns `4`;

Comment: Well, you have created the new section, but never add it to the HTML. Select the parent element of sections and use `appendChild` to append the new section to the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created the element but haven't append it to any parent container. SO, it doesn't exist in the html yet. Use appendChild(lastSection) to it's parent container. Then you'll have four sections.

```js
const lastSection = document.createElement('section');
document.body.appendChild(lastSection) //append it to the required parent(I've added it to the body for example)
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
console.log(allSections.length);
```

```html
<section>1</section>
<section>2</section>
<section>3</section>
```